# App RTC calls not working from ios to ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webrtc, apprtc

Not working on ios to ios
When I'm testing with appRTC server(`https://apprtc.appspot.com` ) calls are working from iOS to iOS, iOS to Android,Android to iOS.

But I'm test with my custom server(`http://192.168.0.100:8080`) calls are not working from iOS to iOS and iOS to Android. But Android to iOS are working fine.

I find below logs when i test with appRTC server and Custom server.

**AppRTC server log**

messages=("{\"sdp\":\"v=0\r\no=- 1775027741179794605 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 127 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:\/tWQo+jqPxhIl3IN\r\na=ice-pwd:2ygl5p2voV6hCnWEoousQ4lf\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 B7:F8:19:8E:8E:4B:7B:2D:08:41:C4:84:02:5F:7A:87:36:70:FC:75:A4:5B:BD:BB:E1:02:C2:00:94:09:50:42\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13CN\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:127 red\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:126telephone-event\/8000\r\na=maxptime:60\r\na=ssrc:2389551740 cname:1Yy7HlmkEzRJ8MGE\r\na=ssrc:2389551740 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0\r\na=ssrc:2389551740 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:2389551740 label:ARDAMSa0\r\nm=video 9 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 100 101 116 117 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:\/tWQo+jqPxhIl3IN\r\na=ice-pwd:2ygl5p2voV6hCnWEoousQ4lf\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 B7:F8:19:8E:8E:4B:7B:2D:08:41:C4:84:02:5F:7A:87:36:70:FC:75:A4:5B:BD:BB:E1:02:C2:00:94:09:50:42\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:video\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap: 4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:100 VP8\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:101 VP9\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:116 red\/90000\r\na=rtpmap:117 ulpfec\/90000\r\na=rtpmap:96 rtx\/90000\r\na=fmtp:96 apt=100\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 1323191592 639993057\r\na=ssrc:1323191592 cname:1Yy7HlmkEzRJ8MGE\r\na=ssrc:1323191592 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:1323191592 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:1323191592 label:ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:639993057 cname:1Yy7HlmkEzRJ8MGE\r\na=ssrc:639993057 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:639993057 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:639993057 label:ARDAMSv0\r\n\",\"type\":\"offer\"}"

**My Custom server log**

messages=({
  "{\"sdp\":\"v"="0\r\no=- 2998020272174880143 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 127 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:BFXSd2bY1pDE8OF3\r\na=ice-pwd:jMWbDoMtoiXueQyB58ap2E3E\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AF:8F:E9:99:B9:4F:94:73:C2:0C:D8:48:40:E7:22:70:00:30:AA:CF:73:0A:BF:C3:D7:91:FB:D1:82:7A:DA:D5\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:127 red\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:126telephone-event\/8000\r\na=maxptime:60\r\na=ssrc:787225427 cname:lIYSgGVkbmqAsNjY\r\na=ssrc:787225427 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0\r\na=ssrc:787225427 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:787225427 label:ARDAMSa0\r\nm=video 9 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 100 101 116 117 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:BFXSd2bY1pDE8OF3\r\na=ice-pwd:jMWbDoMtoiXueQyB58ap2E3E\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AF:8F:E9:99:B9:4F:94:73:C2:0C:D8:48:40:E7:22:70:00:30:AA:CF:73:0A:BF:C3:D7:91:FB:D1:82:7A:DA:D5\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:video\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:100 VP8\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:101 VP9\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:101 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:116 red\/90000\r\na=rtpmap:117 ulpfec\/90000\r\na=rtpmap:96 rtx\/90000\r\na=fmtp:96 apt=100\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 1382966710 2989628045\r\na=ssrc:1382966710 cname:lIYSgGVkbmqAsNjY\r\na=ssrc:1382966710 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:1382966710 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:1382966710 label:ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:2989628045 cname:lIYSgGVkbmqAsNjY\r\na=ssrc:2989628045 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:2989628045 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:2989628045 label:ARDAMSv0\r\n\",\"type\":\"offer\"}";
}

Comment: I am facing the same problem in APPRTCDemo with our local server. It always returns wrong json with our local server.  Did you find any solution ?.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?